# Cannot connect to Pixhawk with Dronekit and 3DR Radios

Tags: dronekit-python

I am running the examples included in the Dronekit 2 downloads.

Although I am able to get things to be fully functional with SITL, I am unable to connect to a real drone.

I am able to connect to the drone with Mission Planner and the 3DR Radios.

I have verified that the Radios are using COM6.

I then disconnect Mission Planner.

I try to run a Python example code "vehicle_state.py" with the line:

vehicle = connect('com6')

I have to remove the "wait_ready = True" parameter because that gives errors.

That issue is still unresolved from a previous post I made.  But SITL works fine without the wait_ready parameter.

Things just sit.

No timeout error either.

Please advise.

Thanks!

Comment: The problem is that the sources to dronekit have changed but the examples were not updated.

The 'wait_ready' parameter was renamed to 'await_params' -- if you change the example, you'll get past this problem, only to run into the next problem, that the vehicle object you get back from connect does not have a member named 'heading' anymore.